# ArcGIS Python SearchCursor file locking?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, cursor, lock

I have a script that gets a value from a shapefile's field to return to the user.

It seems that only when the arcpy.SearchCursor is called ArcMap 10.0 locks the file and it doesn't get removed after the script is finished running.  To get the lock off I have to close ArcMap.  In the script I delete the SearchCursor object after using it as well as the row object.

The way I have the script working is that it tries to delete the workspace folder on subsequent runs but can't because of the lock...until of course I close ArcMap.

Is there any advice on getting this lock to go away?

Answer (score 4):

the problem was solved after going from:

```
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)   
delete = rows.deleteRow  
for row in rows:  
    delete(row)  
del row  
del rows
```

to

```
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)
for row in rows:
    rows.deleteRow(row)
del row
del rows
```

Answer (score 3):

See [Cannot get rid of lock on file geodatabase and feature class created in Python script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/6230/5483).  It looks like the same issue.  I have gotten around it before by explicitly deleting the feature class.  I'm not sure if this will work in all cases.

```
import arcpy

fcPath = 'c:/temp/features.shp'
idFld = 'OBJECTID'
cur = arcpy.SearchCursor(fcPath)
for row in cur:
    id = row.getValue(idFld)
    row = None
cur = None
r = arcpy.Delete_management(fcPath)

print r.getOutput(0)
```

Forcing a garbage collection may work as well, but my hunch is that this has something to do with the internal workings of arcpy or ArcMap.

```
import gc
gc.collect()
```

Comment: I edited this, as the row reference should be removed after each iteration of the cursor, otherwise the call outside the loop is superfluous.

This is also one I voted up as its the only way I could get around the same issue when I had it.

Comment: @Hairy OK, but I think it's a mute point.  Python decrements the references to the previous row _object_ on each iteration when a new row _object_ is assigned to the row _variable_.  `row = None` after the loop simply cleans up the last row assignment.  Moving it inside the loop is duplication of effort.  In any case, the garbage collector should deallocate the memory unless arcpy or ArcMap inerternally maintains a reference to the row objects.

Comment: its ok to agree to disagree, or it being a moot point.  I know that garbage collection in arcpy is flawed, and is actually a lot quicker if you turn it off.  As for the row being set to nothing in the row, I know it works better that way.  Some would say setting anything to none is superfluous, but it isn't.  Have a go at turning your garbage collection off at the start of your script and measure the time differences.  I also use del row, not row = none, but that's another dicussion: try import gc    
gc.disable()

Comment: @Hairy, It hadn't occurred to me to disable the gc.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: This doesn't work for me because I need the feature class.  Also I later get a UpdateCursor on another feature class and this get locked also.  I ended up using mirrors and sleight of hand to get where I need to be.  Not sure how long it will hold up.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't follow...  in your question your say you delete the workspace.  You can move the delete operation to the end of whatever you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are properly deleting both the row and cursor objects (e.g. `del row, rows`) and the lock remains, it's likely because ArcMap itself, not arcpy, is still referencing it.

Is the shapefile referenced by a layer in the table of contents, or is it added to the TOC by your script tool?

If the latter, you might try disabling **"Add results of geoprocessing operations to the display"** under **Geoprocessing->Geoprocessing Options** in ArcMap.

**An additional suggestion:** If you are doing this as a temporary/intermediate dataset, and the number of features is not too large, try using the [`in_memory`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002w0000005s000000) workspace instead of a shapefile to get around the locking problem entirely and get a nice potential performance increase as well.

Just be sure to delete the in_memory workspace or the specific datasets you create there using [Delete (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000052000000) before exiting the script, otherwise it will continue to reside in memory until the application closes.

Lastly I would also note that shapefile locking behavior changed in 10.0 to become more strict by not removing the lock files when you remove a layer from the table of contents. See also this [article](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/38493) and this [related question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14601/arcgis-10-sr-lock-lock-file-how-to-delete).

Comment: It is definitely ArcMap.  I think calling an cursor kills the previous cursors lock.  I call a SearchCursor on a fc..then an UpdateCursor on another fc and the previous lock goes away.  I may call a thrid dummy cursor on a file that will not need to be deleted just to handle the lock killing black box style.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to run your ArcPy script from inside ArcMap?  Unless it's part of an interface or toolbox you've built, you can run it outside ArcMap from a Python console, IDLE, or Eclipse etc (so long as you have an appropriate licence on the machine it's running on).  If this is the case you can write a little Python code to spawn your ArcPy script as a subprocess and the lock should be released when the subprocess closes.

ArcGIS locks are a pain.  I have had situations where a lock persists even after shutting down the machine, which is a monumental pain (usually if Arc has crashed before it can tidy up the locks).  As a last resort, if this happens, use Windows Explorer to find the .LOCK file and delete it manually.  This won't work if it is being accessed by ArcMap or a Python process, so it is ***relatively*** safe... but this is really a Get-Out-of-Jail card and not good practice :)